# How to ignore emit() callback in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like know how can I ignore a emitter callback example

1- I press a Button1 this execute:

```
socket.emit('action', () => { // actions..})
```

2- I press a Button2 and I wanna ignore socket emit previous

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: can you add some more detail/info? Is Button2 emitting the same event? What are the actions? Are you just looking to roll back some sort of state changes or do you want to emit without the actions?

Comment: when I press button2  I want to ignore the emit callback executed by button1..

Comment: I think this is a lot more complicated than you may think. With how vague this is to solve it you would need to have some way to "go back in time" on the server and client. An example of something "going back in time" is the redux devtools. What it essentially would need to do is save the state of everything on every event and then roll it back to the state previous to the event you want to ignore. I highly doubt this is something you want to do. because I don't know enough, I can't really recommend anything, but maybe try to create another event to specifically undo the first events actions.

Comment: well, thanks for your response but I could resolve it. To solve this I made the next:

1- before to press button1 I setted in a variable the current TS, when I do the emit I pass to the server this TS
2- socket server must returns this ts (suppose thtat callback has a delay of 10 seconds)
3- button2 is pressed and update TS again from frontend side
4- when socker server finish the request and execute the callback function declared on frontend there I validate for TS and compare with the first one.

well I'm not sure if you understand me but It was resolved